# CNAME record for multiple Domains

Tags: nginx, dns, cross-domain, cloudflare, cname

I have 2 domains whose DNS I manage on Cloudflare.

For each domain, I own separate EC2 servers which have some apps linked to their assigned domains.

Let's assume 1st domain is `abc.com` and 2nd domain is `xyz.com`

Both the servers have Nginx configured for proxying the requests to diff apps.

Server 1 servers these apps

1. `alpha.abc.com`
2. `beta.abc.com`
3. `gamma.abc.com`

Server 2 servers only `delta.xyz.com`

I have Nginx configuration, sites-available files, etc for all these 4 apps with their proper A records added in Cloudflare.

---

Now my goal is to add a CNAME record so that
`omega.xyz.com` points to `alpha.abc.com/somepath/someid`

**What should I do to achieve this?**

Comment: "Now my goal is to add a CNAME record so that omega.xyz.com points to alpha.abc.com/somepath/someid"  That is not possible because `CNAME`,  as everything in the DNS, deals with names, not URLs, which your second item is. So you will need to map the names only with the CNAME and then have a website handling the path part. Besides that your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Answer (score 2):

CNAME record only contain `domain-name`. So that I think you can config a redirect rule in NGINX server `omega.xyz.com`

```
    location = / {
      rewrite / https://alpha.abc.com/somepath/someid permanent;
    }
```

For advance: Read more at https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/